# Raspberry Pi 4: cannot update nodejs (10.24.1) and npm (6.) to the latest

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, node-modules, raspberry-pi4

For `nodejs`, I did this on my Raspberry PI 4 terminal:

```
>> nodejs --version
>> 10.24.1
>> sudo apt remove nodejs
>> reboot
>> sudo apt install nodejs
>> nodejs --version
>> 10.24.1
```

For `node`, I did this on my Raspberry PI 4 terminal:

```
>> node --version
>> 10.24.1
>> sudo apt remove node
>> reboot
>> sudo apt install node
>> node --version
>> 10.24.1
```

Don't know, I did this couple of times. Finally it remains with same version only. I know there is a 19.2 version `nodejs`. How to install it?

Answer (score 2):

Somebody has to upgrade/compile/check/testing etc, to publish a new version for a software, that's why Nodejs may be out of date from the default stable channels offered by your distro.

Some Linux distribution may provide alternative pkg version (like modules in fedora).

You can always install the software manually, compiling the code, downloading the pkg (raw binary,appimage,deb,rpm etc) from GitHub/website of the project.

Install new repository with bleeding edges build, offered officially or by third-party.

Always make sure the source is safe, either installing repos or using software from the internet.

In this case:
Follow the instruction from [Nodejs on the official website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/).

Node version manager could be an option.

In the end: choose what is best for you.

Comment: Would recommend NVM, usually makes version control far easier.